# ï»¿ encoding issue

Tags: php, html, utf-8, iso-8859-1, byte-order-mark

I'm developing a website using PHP and these strange chars "ï»¿" appears in my page, right on the top of it.
My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><?php echo '';?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

But when I see the source code in the browser, it shows this:

```
ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I don't know if has any relation to the encoding I'm using, because when I change the charset to `charset=utf-8` it disappears but I must use iso-8859-1

Comment: Why must you use `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: I don't know if I must. I started to use it because some chars as "á", "é" appear as �. It's a website in portuguese (PT-Br)

Comment: If you have no good reason to use ISO-8859-1, don't. Save yourself a lot of headaches and just use UTF-8 for everything. Unicode (UTF-8) can encode virtually any possible character on this planet, all other encodings can only encode a limited subset, so you need to make sure you're never using characters outside that subset. You'd need a really good reason to limit yourself like that.

Comment: OK. Gonna try to use UTF-8. But what about those annoying � ? What should I do so they are gone?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) :)

Comment: Also, something I wrote just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233743/php-mysql-html-javascript-i18n-headache/

Comment: How to solve this with powershell: may be it helps someone:

Powershell:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.phtml" | foreach-object {
 $MyFile = Get-Content $_.Fullname
 $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
 [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($_.Fullname, $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write text files without Byte Order Mark (BOM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437666/write-text-files-without-byte-order-mark-bom)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's a [BOM character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is there because the source code files are saved as UTF-8 BOM. Try to save them as UTF-8 no-BOM (or whatever your editor calls it) or indeed ISO-8859-1 if you must use it (...why would you?).

Comment: It depends on the editor you're using. So... what editor are you using?

Comment: @Rafael Sorry, I can't tell you how to do that in Eclipse. Look at the documentation how to set a files encoding.

Comment: Oh man. You've saved my life with that. Saving the file as an ANSI one solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `iso-8859-1`, you need to save your PHP file as `iso-8859-1`.
For detailed instructions, please tell us which editor you're using.

However, I highly recommend that you use UTF8 instead.

Comment: I have already configured Eclipse for that, and it still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Page Info" screen and see what character set the browser thinks you're in.  The odds are that your web server is forcing UTF-8 with its Content-Type header, which trumps the `meta` tag.

Comment: Mozilla Firefox says it's using iso-8859-1

Answer (score -1):

simple solution, just placed your html/php code is start from first line, I am just do that to resolve these problem, and it's work.

Comment: Don't you think that OP _did_ place the code right? Why didn't you check the answer that was _accepted_ (as it - obviously - described the problem and its possible solution quite correctly)?